# Laravel eloquent relationship fetch records upto third level of relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have users table which has a hasOne relationship with vendordetails table.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function vendor_details() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Vendordetail');
    }
}
```

On the other side vendordetails table contains country_id, state_id and city_id and has relationship of belongsTo with Country, State and City model.

Vendordetail.php model is:-

```
class Vendordetail extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function this_country(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Country', 'country_id');
    }

    public function this_state(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Country', 'state_id');
    }

    public function this_city(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Country', 'city_id');
    }

}
```

How can i fetch records of country, state and city if i query on users table.

```
$user = User::with('vendor_details')->first();
```

In this query it only finds the result of vendordetails table, i also wants country, state and city.

Thanks

Comment: try something like $user = User::with('vendor_details.othe_relationship')->first();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To access nested relationship

`$user = User::with(['vendor_details.this_state','vendor_details.this_country','vendor_details.this_city'])->first();`